# Checkbox doesn't change the value

Tags: flutter

I have a big issue with the checkbox. If I tap on checkbox he show that the _value change but after the set state _value comeback to first value. And if I introduce data in the text fields and after that I try to check the box my text disappear.

This is the first state of the value:
`bool _value = false;`

Here is the code for the container where  the checkbox is:

```
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 35.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
              child:( _futureUser == null)

                  ? Column(

                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(

                      child:Row(children:<Widget>[
                        Text('Account type:',style:TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.grey),),
                  SizedBox(width: 13,),
                  CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl(
                   // padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(100, 0, 100, 0),
                    groupValue: segmentedControlGroupValue,
                    children: myTabs,

                    onValueChanged: (i){
                      setState(() {
                        if( i == 0) _role = "patient";
                        else if( i == 1 )_role = "doctor";
                        segmentedControlGroupValue = i;
                        print(_role);
                      });

                    },
                  )])),
                 // SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                  TextField(
                    controller: _namecontroller,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Name',
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.grey),
                        // hintText: 'Nume',
                        // hintStyle: ,
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.redAccent))),

                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  TextField(
                    controller: _usernamecontroller,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Username ',
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.grey),
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.redAccent))),
                    //  onChanged: (val) => newUser.email = val,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  TextField(
                    controller: _email,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Phone ',
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.grey),
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.redAccent))),
                    //  onChanged: (val) => newUser.email = val,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  TextField(
                    controller: _passwordcontroller,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Password ',
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.grey),
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.redAccent))),
                    obscureText: true,
                    //   onChanged: (val) => newUser.password = val,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  TextField(
                    controller: _passwordConfirmcontroller,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Confirm your Password ',
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily:  'Montserrat',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.grey),
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color:Colors.redAccent))),
                    obscureText: true,
                    //   onChanged: (val) => newUser.passwordConfirm = val,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                  Checkbox(
                    value: _value,
                    onChanged: (bool newValue) {
                      print(_value);
                      setState(() {
                        _value = newValue;
                        print(_value);
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20.0),
```

Comment: Can you please show the entire file ? Or the whole method method content though

Comment: One possible condition is you declare variable in Widget build. So when setState/build variable reset again.

Comment: add all code where you are using _value in you code.

Answer (score 0):

I can't immediately tell what the issue could be, but there are a lot of things you could improve now that would make finding it much easier! :)

**1.**
I suggest adding trailing commas to every `))}` and similar structure, so they look like `,),),]`, then hit the auto-formatter (in VSCode Alt+Shift+F), which should make things easier to read.

**2.**
While this

```
if( i == 0) _role = "patient";
else if( i == 1 )_role = "doctor";
```

Does technically work it is rife for unforeseen issues, I recommend adding `{}` around those commands to make sure it doesn't backfire.

**3.**
Also `SetState` should contain as little logic as possible. While it can work with some calculations it is best practice to only pass the new values into `SetState`, so that only the parts that pertain to it will be reloaded.

4.
What's going on with

```
( _futureUser == null)
                  ? Column(
```

Could maye that one change in the meantime and switch to the alternative part of that statement? (just erxtrapolating from what we can see here :) )